# Click on TextField rebuild whole UI in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, screen, textfield, rebuild

Click on TextField rebuild whole UI in flutter (When our screen one or more widget depend on Media Query) How I can solve this issue? This strange behavoiur of media query when we click on textfield  and keyBoard open media query rebulid one more same page in stack.How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make  useInheritedMediaQuer to true.This will help you to solve this issue

```
MaterialApp(
        useInheritedMediaQuery: true,)
```

Comment: Not work, still rebuilds whole UI

Answer (score -1):

This is normal behavior.When you click on TextField and keyboard opens , the viewinsets value changes then your widget rebuild.
Click [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/viewInsets.html)!

You can use MediaQuery.of(context) in seperated   widget to prevent rebuild your whole widget for better performance.

Comment: This is not normal...